# Update Layer Symbology based on 1 field with changing data

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, symbology, data-driven-pages, python-addin

I am running ArcGIS 10.2.2 Version 10.2.2.3552, using ArcMap.

I have quite a big task here and before i attempt it i want to know if it is even possible.  I've looked up some similar questions on here and have some bases, but I need more of a directed starting point.  I have several mxds (100 or so) and each month the data changes.  I have 15 colors and 1 grey color for "other" in my symbology based on 1 field.  Each month the main colors could change though, based on if they had more data then the previous month.

I export these maps based on data driven pages with python.  Is there a way to update symbology based on new statistics for my data driven pages? So the colors are mainly the same but a few rotating colors every month and the old ones going grey, new ones taking their place.  I get the statistics through the "Summary" tool, but i can't find an equal python function for this.

The thing I've looked into the most is representation.  Though I am not sure of the limitations of these and if these even will work with what I am trying to do?

Comment: Have a look at the examples http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/GraduatedColorsSymbology/00s30000005z000000/ on GraduatedColorsSymbology. Although the arcpy.layer says symbology is read only apparently it can be modified with the new values.

Comment: I'm not able to picture what you are describing.  Are you able to include some graphics?  I think you should do your proof of concept based on a simple Python/ArcPy script first before you "complicate" it with a Python add-in and/or Data Driven Pages.  I would be surprised if this is a use case for representations.  SummaryStatistics is the tool you can use for summarizing.

Comment: I found a workaround with Apply layer from symbology.  I took a look at the link Michael provided and with the symbology I am using I don't think its going to work out how i had hoped.